# How to manually call mkl-fftw3 in vs with ivf?

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, fftw, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I have searched many documents, https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-appendix-d-fftw-interface-to-intel-math-kernel-library say that

> For ease of use, FFTW3 interface is also integrated in Intel MKL.

It really works well in vs2017 with ivf2019, where I just use choose to modify 'Use Intel Math Kernel Library' as '/Qmkl...' then all environment configurations are **automatically** satisfied。

But when I follows the tutorial in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-build-mkl-application-in-intel-visual-fortran-msvs to **manually** set the include and lib directory, the same code could also be compiled and linked well(as I see). Howerer, **the results are all zeros**.

The tutorial also mentioned

> Some interface libraries (i.e. mkl_lapack95.lib mkl_blas95.lib fftw3xc_ms) may not Intel® MKL standard libraries, as such 'Step 2 - quick option' does not support them.  You can add those libraries manually if you need to use them.

```
  program main
  implicit none  
  double complex t_in(5,5), t_out(5,5)
  integer*8 plan
  integer i 

  t_in = dcmplx(reshape([1:25],[5,5]))

  call dfftw_plan_dft_2d(plan,5,5,t_in,t_out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_E
 1  STIMATE)
  call dfftw_execute_dft(plan, t_in, t_out)
  call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan)
  PRINT*,t_in
  PRINT*,t_out
  END
```

I also try to explicitly include lib files, it shows no difference

```
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_intel_ilp64.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_sequential.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_core.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_core_dll.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_rt.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_cdft_core_dll.lib'
  !dec$objcomment lib:'mkl_cdft_core.lib'
```

The results are shown as below, for simplicity, I omit several lines.

```
...t_in
(1.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(2.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(3.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(4.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(5.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(6.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(7.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(8.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
...t_out
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
...
```

Thanks for any help, I have been confused for several days.

Comment: Does you (actual) program have "include 'fftw3.f'" (or similar) in the subroutine? Otherwise, FFTW_FORWARD and FFTW_ESTIMATE are undefined... (and should be an error if implicit none is given).

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant to the question itself, but you should link either against LP64 or ILP64 version, not both. See: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-macos-developer-guide-using-the-ilp64-interface-vs-lp64-interface

Comment: and don't mix mkl_rt with ILP64 and mkl_sequential libraries, as mkl_rt will links with mkl_threadind and LP64 libs automatically. You may refer to the MKL User's Guide to take more details

Comment: here is the link to the documentation - https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-using-the-single-dynamic-library